# Is there a method of automating the process of downloading the latest Chrome Driver for a Selenium project?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, pyautogui

I am currently in the process of teaching myself Python and I have chosen to make my first project a Selenium project that can automate my online shopping.

I have the project running fairly smoothly but I can see some potential pitfalls in the near future.

Once Chrome updates to a newer version, will my project fail to work due to having an older Chrome driver installed?

If this is the case, which I assume it is, is there a method to check the correct Chrome Driver is installed and if not, install the correct driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please find below answer :

**use below command to install webdriver manager**

```
pip install webdriver_manager

**Use with Chrome:**

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

for more details please find below link:: 
https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager

Answer (score 0):

**webdriver-auto-update**

There is a package in PyPI and GitHub called `webdriver-auto-update`. It will detect the driver version on your computer and download the latest chrome driver version/release automatically.

**Installation:**

Make sure you have Python installed in your system.
Run the following in your terminal to install:

`pip install webdriver-auto-update`

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_auto_update import check_driver


# Pass in the folder used for storing/downloading chromedriver
check_driver('folder/path/of/your/chromedriver')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Reference link:

https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-auto-update/
https://github.com/competencytestlvl/webdriver_auto_update